# UITextField value is not updating when changing the value

Tags: ios, swift

I have one `UITextField` in my app. When it loads and the user can edit the  `text` of the `UITextField` and send the value to a server. But when doing this, the value entered by the user is not sent to my server.

If the `default value` is `0` and I edit the value of the `UITextField` to send it to the server, my server is still showing `0` as the received value.

Please help me out!

Here is the code where I'm assigning the `UITextField` value to the `String` `variable`. That value is send to the server.

```
var a : String?

 a = myUITextField.text
```

However I don't know whether my value is updating in the declared variable (`a`) or not.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Just put a breakpoint on that line an chekc when it is called and what value is there.

Comment: show some more code!

Comment: There is too little code to help you.

Comment: @Sahil  i am just getting the uitext field value and i am assigning to my varibale thats it. no other code are there. And i am sending this variable as parameter to my server

Comment: simply debug your code . check value before sending it to the server.

Comment: its coming 0.0 as the default value of my uitext field

Comment: print(productQty.text) print(proqty)` its coming 0.0

Comment: where are you assigning this value  proqty = productQty.text

Comment: assigning ??. I din get you !!.

Comment: What event are you targeting when you run this code? Are you by chance running this code in viewDidLoad() ?

Answer (score 0):

You can print the value before sent to server, and can you describe the answer clearly or give me more your code.I guess, maybe you just use productQty.text instead of proqty.

Comment: I did like this ` print(productQty.text)
         print(proqty)` its coming 0.0

Comment: You can set your project to my email, and maybe I can help you, my email is 355086587@qq.com.

Comment: its little bit big project. And its small portion. Cant send that much big project.

Comment: When i change the value in my uitext field, its not showing the value and also its not printing tha value what i have entered in uitext field

Comment: Not showing the value in your UITextFiled? Maybe it is your weight's fault.Or you can print the value in the UITextFiled's delegate.